# How do I retrieve JSON data not on it's top level in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, json

I have JSON data that looks as such:

```
{
"dataset": {
            "id": ,
            "dataset_code": "",
            "database_code": "",
            "name": "",
            "description": "",
            "refreshed_at": "",
            }
}
```

When I go to NSLog the JSON data using the "dataset" identifier it prints fine. However I want to access the next level of JSON data which is what I'm looking to use. However, when I try to NSLog the next level I get an error in xcode. My code looks as such:

```
NSString *query = @"jsonwebsite.com";
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query]];
_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_Array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

So if I use this it's logs fine.

```
NSString *testString = [_Array valueForKey:@"dataset"];
NSLog(@"%@",testString);
```

But as mentioned, I'm looking for the next set of data and when I try this, it gives an error.

```
NSString *testString = [_Array valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@",testString);
```

It returns (null). How would I be able to access the name field in this JSON data?

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`?

Comment: And why are you using an array for a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code.

```
_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_Array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

There is no point to creating an empty array in the first line, only to replace it with a different object in the second line.

Your data contains a dictionary of dictionaries, not an array. You should create a variable `dictionary`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

You should not use `valueForKey` to fetch values from your dictionary. That is a KVO method. Use `objectForKey` instead, or better yet, use modern dictionary syntax:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataSet = dictionary[@"dataset"];

NSString *name = dataSet[@"name"];

if (name == nil) {
  NSLog(@"name is nil");
} 
else if (name.length == 0) {
  NSLog(@"name is empty");
} 
else {
  NSLog(@"Name is %@", name);
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for you're help. You're explanation helped me a lot. I searched stackoverflow and feel like I was trying anything, combing multiple answers, and got lost. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem then you should accept it. (Or one of the other answers, if you think they were better.)

Comment: No problem. I just did!

Answer (score 0):

your json is a `NSDictionary` not a `NSMutableArray`,you used a `NSMutableArray` to recieve a `NSDictionary` was wrong.

test this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSDictionary *subDict = dict[@"dataset"];

NSLog(@"%@", subDict);

NSLog(@"%@", subDict[@"name"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this code:

```
NSString *query = @"jsonwebsite.com";
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query]];
_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_Array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSString *testString = [_Array valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@",testString);
```

into this:

```
NSString *query = @"jsonwebsite.com";
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query]];
_Array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSDictionary *dataSet = [_Array objectForKey:@"dataset"];
NSString *testString = [dataSet objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@",testString);
```

Comment: your _array will lead him to another mistake...,i think he property the _array as a`NSMutableArray` in the interface.

Comment: @ezatu丶actually when he init it already changed the data type to be `id` or whatever the jsonObject is so when he did objectForKey _array is a dictionary. So the init of nsmutablearray will be disregarded.